# Wordpress Sidebar pushed at the bottom on iphone

Tags: iphone, wordpress, safari, sidebar

Getting close to finishing this WordPress website: www.the-hind.com, which displays fine on desktop browsers, but my only issue is that on iPhone ONLY the the sidebar on the right is pushed at the bottom of the page. I tried so many things in CSS but probably have been looking at it for so long that can't see the answer.

I'm sure (wishful thinking) that the solution is something simple & obvious, for an expert like YOU.

Looking forward to any help you can offer.

Answer (score 2):

Your theme is Fully responsive by definition ( http://wordpress.org/themes/blaskan ) and this is how it is supposed to work ( it will not happen only in iPhone, but eventually in any device.

If you want to change it you should change the css file  :

```
http://the-hind.com/wp-content/themes/blaskan/framework.css?ver=3.5.1
```

with the relative parts of the media queries :

```
/** =STRUCTURE MIN: 480px ----- */

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px)
```

and :

```
/** =STRUCTURE MIN: 768px ----- */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)
```

to understand more [read here](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) and also [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/an-introduction-to-css3-media-queries.html#fbid=s3EAjdQ4MO3) or search "media queries" on google ..

Answer (score -1):

The "iPhone only" will be due to screen-size. There will be other devices it happens on. So the key is to edit CSS and add the various sizes. While making your changes, test on all device sizes.

Try using this online and free tool which allows input of any sizes then the testing of multiple screens at once...

[Responsive Design bookmarklet by Benjamin Keen](http://www.benjaminkeen.com/open-source-projects/smaller-projects/responsive-design-bookmarklet/)

If you want a really nice and clear tutorial try this...

[Responsive Web Design by Shay Howe](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/)